# Downgrading MassTransit from 3.4.0 to 3.3.1

Tags: c#, dll, masstransit

I'm trying to download the DLL reference to MassTransit and MassTransit from 3.4.0 to 3.3.1.

I replaced all the instances with the nuget shell and I verified that there are no more referenced instances of the 3.4.0 with AsmSpy (both MassTransit and MassTransit are always referenced as 3.3.1).

```
Reference: MassTransit
    3.3.1.0 by MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport
    3.3.1.0 by BusinessLogic
    3.3.1.0 by Contracts

Reference: MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport
    3.3.1.0 by BusinessLogic
```

Nonetheless, when I try to run the code this exception is thrown:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in MyProject.Tests.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MassTransit, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I did a Clean, a Rebuild, and tried pretty much everything I could think of. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue is with VS. When downgrading a library nuget references the right packet, but the content of the .package and .csproj files might still contain the older (higher) versions.

A text search of the older (higher) of the library showed the points that needed to be manually corrected.